# Moving an item from a list to a document library based on reference number,

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am looking to create a workflow that matches a reference number within a list to a specific document library with the same reference number upon the item being completed within the list, E.g BTP gate Deliverables 100 too Completed gate deliverables 100, 101 to 101 ect. I know how to set up a workflow to move an item to another library in SharePoint Designer upon setting the status to completed just looking to see how it is done based on reference number.

Many thanks

Rhodri

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reference no example? It is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry the Reference number is a column in the list then there is a completed folder with the same name which it needs to go into once the item status is set to complete !

Comment: Which version are you using? 2010 / 2013?

Comment: Using SharePoint 2013